# Why does Biterm Topic Model (BTM) returns coherence score -100?

Tags: python, topic-modeling

I am using `biterm.cbtm` library to train a topic model of about 2500 short posts.
When BTM finishes, I get the following 10 topics, along with the topic coherence value as shown in this picture: https://ibb.co/Kqy992H

I am trying to understand what those negative coherence values mean and why they are so low. I read a lot of related research and I couldn't find one paper that explains the range of the coherence value. Also, most of the papers where about LDA coherence value, as BTM is not well documented.

Does anyone know the range/meaning of the coherence value I am getting?
Why is coherence between -76 and -111?

You can see my code below:

```html
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from biterm.utility import vec_to_biterms
import numpy as np
import pyLDAvis
from biterm.cbtm import oBTM
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from biterm.utility import vec_to_biterms, topic_summuary # helper functions

import pickle
import pandas as pd
from numpy import array
import numpy as np
import logging
import pyLDAvis.gensim
import json
import warnings
import pickle
import pandas as pd
import re
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')  # To ignore all warnings that arise here to enhance clarity

from gensim.models.coherencemodel import CoherenceModel
from gensim.models.ldamodel import LdaModel
from gensim.corpora.dictionary import Dictionary
from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from gensim import corpora, models
from gensim.models import Phrases
import time


def docs_preprocessor(docs):
    tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
    for idx in range(len(docs)):
        docs[idx] = re.sub(r'(https?:\/\/)(\s)*(www\.)?(\s)*((\w|\s)+\.)*([\w\-\s]+\/)*([\w\-]+)((\?)?[\w\s]*=\s*[\w\%&]*)*', '', docs[idx])
        docs[idx] = docs[idx].lower()  # Convert to lowercase.
        if len(docs[idx]) < 50:
            continue
        docs[idx] = tokenizer.tokenize(docs[idx])  # Split into words.
    # Remove numbers, but not words that contain numbers.
    docs = [[token for token in doc if not token.isdigit()] for doc in docs]
    # Remove words that are only one character.
    docs = [[token for token in doc if len(token) > 3] for doc in docs]
    # Lemmatize all words in documents.
    lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
    docs = [[lemmatizer.lemmatize(token) for token in doc] for doc in docs]
    return docs

colnames = ['post']
with open('cleantext.p', 'rb') as handle:
    dict = pickle.load(handle)

dict['text'] = list(filter(None.__ne__, dict['text']))
print("Total posts: " + str(len(dict['text'])))
p_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict)#, skiprows = lambda x: logic(x))
docs = array(p_df['text'])

print("ALL DOCUMENTS: " + str(len(docs)))
docs = docs_preprocessor(docs)
outfile = open("posts.txt", "w+")
total_docs = 0
for sentence in docs:
    if len(sentence) < 3:
        continue
    else:
        total_docs += 1
        for word in sentence:
            result = ''.join([i for i in word if not i.isdigit()])
            outfile.write(result + " ")
        outfile.write("\n")
outfile.close()

print("Total docs: " + str(total_docs))
print("Reading sentences. . .")
texts = open('posts.txt', 'r').read().splitlines()

clear_text = ""
for item in texts:
    clear_text = clear_text + " " + item

vec = CountVectorizer(stop_words='english')
print("Building Vectors. . .")
X = vec.fit_transform(texts).toarray()
print("Building Vocabulary. . .")
vocab = np.array(vec.get_feature_names())
biterms = vec_to_biterms(X)

print("BTM modelling. . .")
btm = oBTM(num_topics=10, V=vocab)

print("\n\n Train Online BTM ..")
btm.fit(biterms, iterations=100)
topics = btm.transform(biterms)

print("\n\n Topic coherence ..")
topic_summuary(btm.phi_wz.T, X, vocab, 10)

#I am getting a weird error about pyLDAvis here. Why?
print("\n\n Visualize Topics ..")
vis = pyLDAvis.prepare(btm.phi_wz.T, topics, np.count_nonzero(X, axis=1), vocab, np.sum(X, axis=0))
pyLDAvis.save_html(vis, 'btm.html')
```

Comment: Anyone familiar with BTM on python!?

Answer (score 0):

I guess we can refer to the idea in coherence understanding of LDA since the formula should be the same.:)

You may take a look at the interpretation here: :)
[Negative Values: Evaluate Gensim LDA with Topic Coherence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50607378/negative-values-evaluate-gensim-lda-with-topic-coherence)